Downloads in WebView in C# .NET MAUI
I'm Manuel and I'm new here, so I apologize for any errors.
I'm developing an Android/iOS app using C# and .NET MAUI. It works fine, but I have a problem with a WebViewer. For some reason, I need to include into the app a web service that the company where I work provides, and for do that I simply used a WebView defined into C# code (because it's dynamic).
MainGrid.Children.RemoveAt(1);
MainGrid.Add(ALoader);
ALoader.IsVisible = true;
ALoader.IsRunning = true;

webViewerS.Source = "https://www.myurl.it/Services";
Grid.SetColumn(webViewerS, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(webViewerS, 5);
Grid.SetRow(webViewerS, 1);

ALoader.IsVisible = false;
ALoader.IsRunning = false;
MainGrid.Children.RemoveAt(1);
MainGrid.Add(webViewerS);

ALoader is defined into MainPage.xml and is an ActivityIndicator.
Into my URL, users compile a form  and then submit it, so they can see the results of the compiled form. These results can be downloaded - pressing a button - from the site as PDF or whatever the user choose.
But in the app, when I press the download button from the site, nothing happens. Seems like if I had never pressed it.
Can someone help me?
Thank you so much

The web view doesn’t have built in download capability.  You have to provide that yourself

Okay, thank you for your answer. How should I do that?

If you want to implement Download function in Webview, you could try using Handler.
For Android, you could use DownloadListener on the WebView and use the DownloadManager to download the file. You may refer to the similar question on StackOverflow : Download files in MAUI Android WebView.
For iOS, you also have to use Handler to deal with the download function yourself. You should use WKNavigationDelegate and WKDownloadDelegate. To implement the function in iOS, you may refer to the solution from Download files in MAUI iOS WebView.
Hope it helps!

Thank you for answering, but I see your links explain it using Java, while I'm using C#.
Anyway, I tried to search something similar, but I didn't found anything. I onlye noticed that my storage read and write permissions are denied, despite I specified that into my AndroidManifest.xml.

What Android API version do you use?

I'm using Android 14, so API version should be 34 if i'm not mistaken

The READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has been removed since android13. You may refer to this SO answer: it does not prompt me for media access permission. (Android 13 API level 33) using xamarin forms.
